# matrix differentiation

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

What is the derivative of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{c}$ respect to $\mathbf{B}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n\times m$ matrix,  $\mathbf{B}$ is a $m\times k$ matrix, and  $\mathbf{c}$ is a $k\times 1$ vector.

Comment: Is the map $\ni\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}B\mapsto ABc\in\mathbb{R}^n$ linear for fixed $A,c$? What would that mean for its differential?

Comment: @Max, I have changed the function. It is not linear.

Comment: @Hossein: Please ask your new version as a new question (and change this back to the old one and accept one of the given answers), as now both answers do not answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the map $\def\M#1#2{\operatorname{Mat}_{#1,#2}(\mathbf R)}$
$$ f: \M mk \to \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^n, \qquad B \mapsto ABc $$
is linear, hence the derivative is constant, it is given at any $B \in \M mk$ by $f$ itself, that is 
$$ f'(B): \M nk \to \R^n, \qquad H \mapsto AHc $$

Comment: what is matrix $H$? is it $\mathbf{I}_{m , k}$?

Comment: @Hossein $H$ is not a fixed matrix.  At any matrix $B$, $f'(B)$ is a *linear function* from the matrices to $\Bbb R^n$, and the function is defined by $[f(B)](H) = AHc$. This version of the derivative is referred to as the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative), and it is the most "mathematically natural" derivative to use in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a single value decomposition ${\bf B} ={\bf U_{m\times m}\Sigma_{m\times k} V^*_{k\times k}}$.

Define a function $f({\bf B})=\bf{ABc}$ then, that is
$$f'({\bf B})=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{\bf ABc} - {\bf A U}({\bf\Sigma}+ h {\bf I_{m\times k}}) \bf{V^*}{\bf c}}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{{\bf ABc} - {\bf ABc}+ h{\bf A U I_{m\times k}V^*  c}}{h}=
{\bf A U I_{m\times k}V^*  c}
$$

This is almost the definition of the derivative, just instead of perturbing $(+h)$ the matrix its singular values being perturbed.

Comment: please note the dimension of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{c}$. We cannot multiply these two.

Comment: yup, I will fix it now

Comment: What you've given here isn't so much the full derivative as it is some strange kind of partial derivative.  Because we have a function from matrices to vectors, the derivative doesn't "fit" nicely into a matrix.

Comment: this definition behave correct when $m=k$ , in which case you can write it as a regular derivatie, such as $({\bf B}+h)_{ij}={\bf B}_{ij}+h$ . Anyway, this is certainly not a partial derivative.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom read when $n=k$